# Spring boot data rest/jpa @JoinTable insertion

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I'm creating a MySQL database as followed :
[database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhTcq.png)

the Country and Province tables are pre-filled with data. I have the application running and can get stuff no problem, and also the join table `person_has_address` works when getting.

however, when I insert data using post I want to be able to set the ID of the province, and let spring data jpa just add that number to `add_pro_id` in the Address table. For example, when I post the following json:

```
{ "firstName":"bilbo", "lastName":"baggings", "address":{"street":"streetName", "streetNum":3, "zipcode":"1337GG", "city":"TheCity", "province":{"name":"aProvinceName"}} }
```

jpa should see that `aProvinceName` exists and grab that `id` and add that to `add_pro_id`.

Now it just insert `aProvinceName` as new value in province and add the new `id` to `add_pro_id`.

The person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="per_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="per_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="per_surname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="per_birth_date")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name="per_fax")
    private String fax;

    @Column(name="per_phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="per_email")
    private String email;


    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="person_has_address", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="pha_per_id", referencedColumnName = "per_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="pha_add_id", referencedColumnName = "add_id")})
    private Address address;

// getters and setters
```

This is the person repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

This is the address class:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="add_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "add_street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="add_street_num")
    private int streetNum;

    @Column(name="add_zip")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(name="add_city")
    private String city;


    @JoinColumn(name="add_pro_id", referencedColumnName = "pro_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Province province;

// getters and setters
```

Province class:

```
@Entity
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="pro_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="pro_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pro_cou_id")
    private Country country;
// getters and setters
```

And lastly country class:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cou_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="cou_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;
// getters and setters
```

I've tried adding `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`, but the application then just inserts `NULL` values in my database. I've also tried working with `@primarykeyjoins`, but to no success.

if anyone knows how I should tackle this problem I would much appreciate it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work like that. If there is an existing province you need to load that and attach it yourself.

Comment: I thought that spring data rest was able to do it out of the box, but i see i was wrong. Ill create some custom implementation. Thanks for your advice.